# Route params return undefined value in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to pass parameters to a route while navigating to another screen in React Native, but **route.params** returns **undefined** . I am using react navigation version 6.

I have a **login** screen structured as follows:

```
export const Login = ({ navigation }) => {

const [data, setData] = useState("My data")

const renderButton = () => {
    console.log("Data test", data)/*I have tested and the Data value is defined at this point*/
    return (
      <View style={{ margin: SIZES.padding * 3 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            height: 60,
            backgroundColor: COLORS.black,
            borderRadius: SIZES.radius / 1.5,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center'
          }}
          onPress={() => {
            /* 1. Navigate to the Home route with params */
            navigation.navigate('Home',
              {
                data: data
              }

            );
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: COLORS.white, ...FONTS.h3 }}>Continue</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }

}
```

The code for the **Home** screen is as follows:

```
export const Home = ({ navigation, route }) => {

    const {data} = route.params

    useEffect(() => {

        //I have attempted to console.log as follows but I get Undefined in both cases

        console.log(data)
        console.log(route.params)

    },[])
}
```

I also understand that the issue could be caused by nested stack navigation so I have also shared my **App.js** code below

```
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false
        }} initialRouteName="onBoarding">
        <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding" component={Onboarding} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Passenger" component={Passenger} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Tabs} /> {*/ Trying to pass the params here/*}
        <Stack.Screen name="SearchRoutes" component={SearchRoutes}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Vehicles" component={Vehicles}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Payment" component={Payment}></Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen name="Receipt" component={Receipt}></Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen name="Conductor" component={Conductor}></Stack.Screen>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, nested navigators cause this problem but not your problem. Just try that, if it doesn't work try to terminate the app and run "yarn start" again.

```
navigation.navigate('Root', {
  screen: 'Home',
  params: { data: data },
});
```

I hope it will work!